# Are all Levy processes memoryless?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationarity

We know that the two canonical Levy processes, namely the Wiener process and Poisson process, are both memoryless, so I wonder if there are any Levy process that is not memoryless. Specifically, are these two properties equivalent:

[independent stationary increments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process) <=> [memorylessness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Levy processes are [Markov processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/Markov_process), a property of stochastic processes distinct, but related to memorylessness as presented in the Wikipedia article you link to, where it refers to a property of distributions. Note that the Markov property is sometimes also (informally) referred to as memorylessness.

The Markov property of Levy processes is indeed a consequence of the independence of increments. However, continuous diffusions (other than Brownian motion) are Markov processes, but they do not possess independent increments.

Comment: Since the two canonical Levy processes, namely the Wiener process and the Poisson process, are both memoryless (defined in the link of my question), can you give an example of a Levy process that is not memoryless?

Comment: If by memoryless, you mean that the process has the Markov property, it is not possible to give such an example, since as I explained, all Levy processes are Markov (but not all Markov processes are Levy - although in a certain sense Levy processes are the building blocks for Markov processes like Brownian motion is the building block for diffusions). The distinction that I (and Levis in his answer) am pointing out is between the memoryless property for a *distribution*, which is the subject of the article you linked, and the memoryless property for processes (a.k.a. Markov property).

Comment: But the memoryless property for a distribution and the Markov property "are connected at a deeply theoretical level", as pointed out by the Wikipedia article about [memorylessness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness). Since all Levy processes are Markov, I wonder if there is any Levy process that doesn't have the memoryless property (for a distribution). Thanks.

Comment: Brownian motion at time $t$ has the normail $N(0,t)$ distribution, and this distribution not have the memoryless property (only the exponential distribution does). The connection between the exponential distribution and Levy processes is that the holding times of a compound Poisson process are independent and have exponential distribution.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

Independent stationary increments is related to the index of a sequence (set) of random variables ($X_t-X_x\stackrel{d}{=}X_{t-s}$) while memorylessness relates to the same random variable and the events of interest ($P(X>t+s\vert X>t)=P(X>s)$).